# UIWebview Image Preview is not appropriate in Landscape Orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiwebview

In my iOS application, I'm loading an image in UIWebview which is from documents directory. I have to Preview that image in Portrait and landscape Orientations. Image looks good in Portrait mode but in landscape mode image appears to be zoomed in. how to show image in landscape mode without any Zoom.

Below is the piece code for the Reference.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.fileName];
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:pdfUrl];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[self.webView sizeToFit];
```

Can any one suggest me how to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: if it is just an image on url, instead of showing on UIWebView, you may try showing on UIImageView.
Take the data from url with NSData and assign it o UIImage and load it

Comment: i need to launch it webview